# 3D graphics library for .NET

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, directx

I would like to learn to make simple 3D applications for Windows 7 / desktop. By that, I mean spheres, triangles or pixels moving around in 3D space. It does not have to be very complicated as of yet.
For this, I would like to use C# language with .NET (Java/C++ is my second priority).

I know this has been asked many times around the internet, but I feel like many of the questions are outdated, many APIs deprecated and tutorials too old.

I was thinking about learning XNA, but then I learned that [Microsoft does not plan to develop and support it anymore.](http://indiegames.com/2013/02/its_official_xna_is_dead.html) SharpDX also seemed like a good way to go, but that seems to be aimed for Windows Store and Phone apps.

While looking on the internet, Managed DirectX seemed exactly what I was looking for (the syntax, the complexity), but again, that is way **too deprecated** for me to use.

Can you please guide me what I should learn to create simple yet solid 3D applications?

Comment: Look at [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) and [renderstack](http://neure.ath.cx/renderstack_new) it is not DirectX, but OpenGL.

Comment: #Ja75
Thanks for the comment. I have looked at OpenTK, but it worries me a little. It seems that there is no updates since 2010 and there are some compatibility problems with newer version of VS.

Comment: The 2010 release is a bit old, but the SVN trunk is stable. I've been using it for a while with no issues. If you want something a bit more cutting edge, there's [a fork of OpenTK on GitHub](https://github.com/andykorth/opentk) that a few of us have been contributing to since the original maintainer of OpenTK has been busy with life for the past while.

Comment: @Janman - I have been using OpenTK for immediate mode OpenGL (direct draw of primitives) like you described.

Comment: SharpDX supports Windows Desktop as well, as clearly stated on the website http://sharpdx.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/). It's an open-source, free, managed library for DirectX (DirectX 11). Each release coincides with a DirectX release, so most of the time it's pretty up-to-date. I've used it and it was quite easy to get started. [Here (scroll down)](http://slimdx.org/features.php) is a comparison with other possibilities you mentioned.

Comment: Hello!
This seems pretty much like what I am looking for. I will dig into it and report in a few days if this helped!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Links provided are no longer valid.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest is probably to use WPF 3D. This is a retained mode graphics system, so if you don't have huge needs (ie: special shaders for effects, etc), it's very easy to setup and use directly.

Otherwise, a more elaborate 3D system, such as XNA, may be more appropriate. This will be more work to setup, but give you much more control.

1. [Tutorial 1: Displaying a 3D Model on the Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203897%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)
2. [WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23332/WPF-3D-Primer)
3. [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791)

Answer (score 6):

In the OpenGL world I have been using [OpenTK](https://opentk.net/). I had to build on top of the existing code with `C#` to get to display flat geometrical objects without shading and realistic effects.

Here is an example:

[image: render]

Generated from the code:

```
void InitModels()
{
    Scene.CoordinateSystem cs1 = new Scene.CoordinateSystem(world.Ground)
    {
        DrawSize = 1,
        Visible = false
    };
    Scene.CoordinateSystem cs2 = new Scene.CoordinateSystem(world.Ground, 0.6 * vec3.J)
    {
        DrawSize = 0.5,
        Orientation = rot3.RotateXDegrees(-15)
    };
    Scene.Cube cube = new Scene.Cube(cs1)
    {
        CubeSize = 0.5
    };
    cs2.AddPoint(new point3(vec3.O,1), Color.Firebrick, 15);
    var line = cs2.AddLine(new line3(-vec3.I, vec3.I), 20, Color.SlateGray, 2);
    line.SetPattern(0xFF0F, GeometryTest.Scene.Stripple.Scale2);

    cube.BindTexture(5, GeometryTest.Properties.Resources.julia, true);
    cube.AddText(3, "OpenTK 1.0", Color.DarkMagenta, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

}
```

Comment: See [Notice of leave](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/commit/2e51fe019771f4c70b15bb25b3a560f712a45fbf): It seems the project owner is not around, so the project will not be updated anymore.